# Show that for any commutative ring $R$, $R[X] \otimes R[Y] \simeq R[X,Y]$.

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Show that for any commutative ring $R$,

$$R[X] \otimes R[Y] \simeq R[X,Y].$$

I know that I have to first take a bilinear map from $R[X] \times R[Y]$ to $R[X,Y]$ and then it induces a linear map from $R[X] \otimes R[Y]$ to $R[X,Y]$. But what is the required bilinear map here that will work? I proceed by taking $(f(x),g(y)) \mapsto f(x)g(y)$.

Will that work? Please help me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that your map should work. Indeed, the map is bilinear and thus induces a linear map (call it $\phi)$. We check that $\phi$ is an isomorphism. It is easy to see it is onto, so we only need to check whether it is 1-1. Notice that all tensors can be written as linear combinations of tensors of the form $x^i \otimes y^j$. So, suppose that $\phi(\displaystyle\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}x^i\otimes y^j)=\phi(\displaystyle\sum_{i,j} b_{i,j}x^i\otimes y^j)$ (where the sums are finite and some of the $a_{i,j}$ and $b_{i,j}$ might be $0$). Then for each $i,j$, we get that $a_{i,j}=b_{i,j}$. So $\displaystyle\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}x^i\otimes y^j=\displaystyle\sum_{i,j} b_{i,j}x^i\otimes y^j$. This means that $\phi$ is 1-1.

Comment: My map is defined by $(f(x),g(y)) \mapsto f(x)g(y)$. How is that onto? If we take any irreducible polynomial $f(x,y) \in R[X,Y]$ then what would be the pre-image of $f(x,y)$ under this map?

Comment: For instance if we take $f(x,y)=xy+1$?

Comment: So, $x^i \otimes y^j \mapsto x^iy^j$. Any polynomial in two variables has the form $\displaystyle\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}x^iy^j$. For such a polynomial $\displaystyle\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}x^i\otimes y^j$ maps to it. In your example, this would be $1\otimes 1 + x\otimes y$

Comment: Remember that not every element of the tensor product is a pure tensor (i.e. a tensor of the form $\alpha \otimes \beta$ as opposed to a linear combination of these).

Comment: Yeah I have understood @Jonathan Dunay. Many many thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Are they isomorphic as algebras?

Comment: I think they indeed are; by the property of algebra homomorphism. Isn't it so?

Comment: I believe so. It should be straight forward to check that it works out.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion showing something is isomorphic to the tensor product is easier if we just show that it has the universal property. Define the map $i:R[X]\times R[Y]\to R[X,Y]$ by $(p(x),q(y))\mapsto p(x)q(y).$ This is certainly a bilinear map. Now we want to show that if $\phi:R[X]\times R[Y]\to M$ is a bilinear map in $R$-Mod, there is a unique map $\bar{\phi}$ from $R[X,Y]\to M$ that has the property that $\bar\phi\circ i=\phi$, and $\bar\phi$ is linear. For any such map $\phi$, we can define $\bar\phi$ by $\bar\phi(x)=\phi(x)$, $\bar\phi(y)=\phi(y)$, $\bar\phi(1)=\phi(1)$, and extending via the universal property of the polynomial ring. So this map exists. Why is it unique? Any map which commuted would have to send $i(x)$ to $\phi(x)$, and similarly $i(y)$ to $\phi(y)$. So this object is the tensor product.

Comment: What is $M$ here?

Comment: @DebabrataChattopadhyay.$M$ is an arbitrary $R$-module.  To verify the universal property, this has to hold for every $M$ and every map to $M$.